# python regex - totaling number of unique patterns in string

Tags: python, regex, string

Forigve me if this is a duplicate, but I'm seeing only so many simple methods for solving my problem of locating the total number of unique instances between two sub strings: 'Ha' and 'ha'

Here is my code with example texts following that:

```
import re
def ha_counter(laughing):
    if not laughing: 
        return 0
    else:
        return len(re.findall(r'Ha',r'ha'))
```

If string input is empty, return 0, otherwise provide the number of times each of those substrings appear.

```
Test.assert_equals(ha_counter(""), 0)
Test.assert_equals(ha_counter("hahahahaha"), 1)
Test.assert_equals(ha_counter("hahahahahaHaHaHa"), 2)
```

Comment: Why are you hardcoding `r'ha'` in `ha_counter` instead of using `laughing`?

Comment: good point, but does re.findall allow me to specify the patterns + but the argument `laughing`?

Comment: It expects the first argument to be a pattern not patterns and the second argument in the string itself. Please check the docs instead of wondering about it.

Comment: Make your pattern `r'[Hh]a'`.  Or without `re` - `s.lower().count('ha')`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using negative lookahead:

```
re.findall(r"Ha(?!.*Ha)","hahahahahaHaHaHa")
Out[5]: ['Ha']

re.findall(r"ha(?!.*ha)","hahahahahaHaHaHa")
Out[6]: ['ha']
#combine the two together with or
re.findall(r"(ha(?!.*ha)|Ha(?!.*Ha))","hahahahahaHaHaHa")
Out[7]: ['ha', 'Ha']
```

https://regex101.com/r/bk8v1s/1